# Firebase + VueJS: Highlighting data in a v-for loop

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I am making a user- / login- / authentication-system with Firebase and VueJS.

I wonder how to highlight the name of each person that is online (has an entry in my firebase-`sessions`-list).

My database-structure:

for users:

```
- users:
  - [userKey]:
     - ... user information
```

for sessions:

```
- sessions:
  - [userKey]:
     - ... session information
```

The template part:

```
<table>
  <tr class="user" v-for="user in $store.state.authentication.users">
    <td class="name">{{ user.name }}</td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

You may add a class to td if user is online

```
<table>
  <tr class="user" v-for="user in $store.state.authentication.users">
    <td class="name" v-bind:class="getUserStatusClass(user)">
        {{ user.name }}
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

You also have to add a method to vue instance, like

```
methods: {
    getUserStatusClass: function (user) {
        if(// userKey is in sessons) {
            return 'active'
        }

        return ''
    }
},
```

A 'active' CSS class will be added to td if user is online. Than you can edit the style for 'active' CSS class